# Redirect to a remote form, fill it out, and submit it

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

I run the website http://gearsbook.net which is a miniature social network for Gears of War players.  I am working on making updates to the site to make it more useful, as it is currently very basic.

One of the features that users have requested is the ability to link to their game statistics.  These statistics are available at http://gearsofwar.xbox.com/WebStats/default.htm, however, the only way to see individual statistics is to fill out the text field on the left with an Xbox LIVE Gamertag and submit.  There are no available static links to a profile, like http://gearsofwar.xbox.com/WebStats/default.htm?Gamertag=player; the only way to reach a player's statistics is through the form which uses a POST action.

I honestly don't know how to approach this situation.  The only way I could think of would be to possibly use Javascript...somehow.  Or maybe frames?  I honestly don't know what I should do.  The ideas I have are quite vague, and am wondering if what I want to do is possible by any means.

The end result I want is for users to be able to click on a link from my site, and end up at a particular player's stats (in a new tab/window), which means somehow I need a way to automatically fill in the form and submit it.  Can this be done?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind - this may well violate the terms of use on the Gears Xbox site.

Comment: You could do the POST server side in a script.  Check the terms of use or ask the other webmaster, though.  The upside of asking instead of just doing is that they might give you access or instruction on an otherwise unknown internal API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create an iframe in your web page. name it "gearswarscoreframe"
2. Leave it blank
3. When you need to load player's score, set URL of iframe to a ASP / JSP / PHP page that sends html with a form pre-filled. Use name of the  iframe to locate it in dom and set url.
4. In this form that has action=url where URL is the one that accepts POST request
5. In the same iFrame, have a Javascript funnction that is called on "onLoad" on Iframe
6. Submit the form in this Javascript function
7. Iframe should now show player's score

Comment: I haven't tried this yet.  I think I get the general idea but I'll have to figure out the implementation details I suppose.  I guess I was on track in thinking I'd need frames and JS.